# Does Extending Multiple Nav_Menu_Walkers Allow Nested Menus?

Tags: menus, customization, dropdown, walker

Essentially I'm trying to add multiple sub nav menus and I'm pretty close but I just can't seem to find the right tack to solve my problem ...

I'm using a variation of a Stu Nichols CSS Menu ...

Code explains better ;-)

The relationship required to build this menu would have the top level elements as list-items, child-containers as divs and children and siblings {nth child} as uls ... So the structure would be the following ...

```
<li><a href='#'>parent</a>
    <div>child-container
    <ul><!--1st Child -->
        <li>item</li>
         ...
    </ul>
    <ul><!--Sibling -->
        <li>item</li>
         ...
    </ul>
    <ul><!--Sibling -->
        <li>item</li>
         ...
    </ul>
    </div> 
</li>
```

My current line of thought is to add an additional nav_menu_walker to build the sub-menu lists ... However, I'm not sure if I can pass multiple walker's as args to wp_nav_menu ... IE ... ASSERT

```
    $menu_params = array (

'theme_location'  => 'primary',
'menu'            => 'Main Menu', 
'container'       => 'div', 
'container_class' => 'nav', 
'container_id'    => FALSE,
'menu_class'      => FALSE, 
'menu_id'         => FALSE,
'echo'            => TRUE,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => FALSE,
'after'           => FALSE,
'link_before'     => FALSE,
'link_after'      => FALSE,
'items_wrap'      => "\n\t" . '<ul>%3$s</ul>' . "\n",
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => new Top_Nav_Menu_Walker()
    <!-- Can I Add another Walker Here? -->
);

echo "\t\t<div id=\"navigation\">\n\t\t\t";

wp_nav_menu( $menu_params );

echo "\t\t</div>\n";

}
```

To obtain the parent -> child-container relationship I've simply added div and ul to the start_lvl function ... Here's where I'm having issues determining how I can create multiple siblings ...

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);     
    $output .=  "\n$indent<div>\n";
    $output .=  "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}
```

In order to add classes to the top level anchor elements I have a custom walker. In the start_el function I've injected classes for the anchor items based on the parent class.

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    /* inject some anchor classes */

    if(  $this->$depth == 0) {
        if ( in_array( 'two', $item->classes ) || in_array( 'three', $item->classes )) {
            $item->class = 'oneCol fly';
        }
        if ( in_array( 'four', $item->classes )) {
            $item->class = 'twoCol fly';
        }
    };

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

  $output .= in_array( 'sub_nav_h4', $item->classes ) ? "\n" . $indent . "<h4>\n" : '';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    /*  This 'should' always be true as WP doesn't support anchor classes    */

    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->class    )       ?   ' class="'  . esc_attr( $item->class            ) . '"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
```

Here's the navigation structure I'm trying to achieve ...

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="noCol one"><a href="/">One</a>       </li>
            <li class="threeCol two"><a class="oneCol fly" href="/two/">Two</a> 
                <div>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Egestas Sed</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Consequat Leo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Lacinia &amp; Blandit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Interdum</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Pellentesque Velit</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Lacinia &amp; Blandit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Interdum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Donec non Fringilla</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Fusce Ullamcorper</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Facilisis</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Tristique</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Donec</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Sapien</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Purus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Congue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Mattis</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Integer nec Diam</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Morbi Eget Pharetra</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Nulla &amp; Orci</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Eget Sapien Sodales</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Aenean</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Velit Ligula</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Maecenas</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="threeCol three"><a class="oneCol fly" href="/three/">Three</a> 
                <div>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Egestas Sed</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Consequat Leo</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Pellentesque Velit</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Lacinia &amp; Blandit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Interdum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Donec non Fringilla</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Fusce Ullamcorper</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Facilisis</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Tristique</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Donec</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Sapien</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Purus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Congue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Mattis</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Integer nec Diam</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Morbi Eget Pharetra</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Nulla &amp; Orci</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Eget Sapien Sodales</a></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Aenean</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Velit Ligula</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Maecenas</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </li>

                <li class="twoCol four"><a class="twoCol fly" href="/four/">Four</a>
                <div>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Ut vel Cursus</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Maecenas imperdiet </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Congue Metus</a></li>
                        <li class="fly"><a class="fly" href="#url">Vitae Luctus</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#url">Purus Pellentesque</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#url">Pellentesque Sed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#url">Felis Nunc</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="#url">Morbi Placerat Luctus</a></h4></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Ut &amp; Eleifend</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Feugiat Euismod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#url">Tempus Condi</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="noCol five"><a href="/five/">Five</a></li>
                <li class="noCol six"><a href="/six/">Six</a></li>
                <li class="noCol seven"><a href="/seven">Seven</a></li>
        </ul>
</div> <!--</div class="nav"> -->
</div><!--</div id="navigation"> -->
```

Comment: That structure is imposed by the CSS, right? If so, you need to rethink you CSS code. Learn about pseudo elements, like :nth-child, :before, :after. I highly doubt it that you cannot implement e certain menu design with WP's default menu markup. Can you post a screenshot of how this menu is supposed to look?

Comment: I tried uploading a screen shot but I don't think I've got the rep here yet :-) fwiw ... this menu works like a champ as a static menu ... NP there ... it's adding multiple unordered lists via a menu walker I'm struggling with ... thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @EddieB you could always link to the screenshot on an image hosting site

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I'd just use a single menu and then apply a CSS class (in the backend) to the navigation element you want the  to be.

It's simple enough to add a CSS class in the Menu editing pane, and that solves a lot of your difficulties since you can just check for the presence of that string in your custom walker.

Comment: Thanks Michael ... That's what I'm currently doing and I'm able to get one sub-menu unordered list ... I just can't seem to add multiple lists per menu ...

Comment: Essentially the issue is being able to add multiple lists for a single child container I.E. parent {li} -> child_container {div} -> child {ul} | sibling {ul} | sibling {ul}

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your menu by using walker.

```
include('subMenu.php');
$menu =  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'YOUR-MENU-NAME','menu_class' => 'megamenu','walker' => new subMenu));
```

create a file subMenu.php in theme folder add below code.

```
<?php
class subMenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

    if( 'parent' == $item->title ){
        $output .= '<div> //child-container
        <ul>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Egestas Sed</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Consequat Leo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Lacinia &amp; Blandit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Interdum</a></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Pellentesque Velit</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Lacinia &amp; Blandit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Interdum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Donec non Fringilla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Fusce Ullamcorper</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Facilisis</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Tristique</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Donec</a></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Sapien</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Purus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Congue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Mattis</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Integer nec Diam</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Morbi Eget Pharetra</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Nulla &amp; Orci</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Eget Sapien Sodales</a></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="#url">Aenean</a></h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Velit Ligula</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#url">Maecenas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        ';
    }
    $output .= "</li>\n";  
    }
}
```